# How to break foreach loop from a XDebug session?

Tags: php, foreach, phpstorm, xdebug, break

I have a foreach loop and that is doing some time consuming stuff:

```
$someHugeArray = [...]; // having beyond 300 to 1000 items

foreach ($someHugeArray as $item) {
    $this->applyTimeConsumingMagic($item);
}
```

When debugging this I try to avoid iterating all of them items, so I am often writing escape code along the lines of:

```
foreach ($someHugeArray as $i => $item) {
    $this->applyTimeConsumingMagic($item);

    if ($i > 10) { break; } // @fixme: should not go live
}
```

And as the comment indicates, something like this did once go live making me feel like an amateur.

Is there some way to break the `foreach` loop from an XDebug session without writing var_dumpy code? As an IDE I use PhpStorm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not find a way to break a foreach loop on the fly, yet the best next thing one can do is to decrease the array size on the fly.

- Set a breakpoint after you set up your array, at best before the loop starts. (It does work inside the loop as well, yet could have weird behavior)
- Select `Evaluate expression` phpstorm's debug window or use shortcut, default should be <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>
- run `$someHugeArray = array_slice($someHugeArray, $offset = 0, $length = 10);`

Besides [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) one could also use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) if one wants to filter by more specific conditions using a closure.

Now you have a small array, enjoy fast execution time without having to worry to clean up after your debug session.

Answer (score 0):

This will break the loop on the 10th run through - but obviously can be set to say 2 or 3 etc:

```
$myArray = $this->getHugeDataArray();
$i       = 0; //here we set i to 0 so we can count to 10

foreach ($myArray as $key => $value)
{
    $i++;
    if ($i == 9) {break;}

    //rest of actual code
}
```

Comment: The danger of this approach is that it will be be part of the codebase and hence prone to erroneous commits. My question was to counter that very issue. If you also would use this in the `Evaluate Expression` feature of phpstorm, then it's downside is that it's much more verbose than `array_slice`.

Comment: @k0pernikus good point, though you don't have to keep it in the code ;) haha but I can remove if you'd prefer? :)